# Hibernate 6.2 envers classcastexception BasicValue to Component

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-envers

Hi all I have spent days trying to figure out this error.  I am upgrading from hibernate 5.5.3 to hibernate 6.2.16.

On start up and deploy my ear file to Wildfly 29 this is the error I get:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.Component (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.Component are in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final' @3f36ff6d)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.IdMetadataGenerator.addIdAndGetMappingData(IdMetadataGenerator.java:204)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.generateFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:270)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.EntitiesConfigurator.configure(EntitiesConfigurator.java:77)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:129)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalMappingContributorImpl.contribute(AdditionalMappingContributorImpl.java:50)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.lambda$processAdditionalMappingContributions$0(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:383)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)
ecoconnect-mintaka-wildfly-1  |     at org.hibernate@6.2.16.Final//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.processAdditionalMappingContributions(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:380)
```

I have looked at *IdMetadataGenerator.java:204* and made sure all my @ManyToOne are mapped correctly - they are all mapped to entities and not any Strings or numeric types.
I cannot get any more verbose logs out - I have set org.hibernate to DEBUG level already

If someone could please point me in the right direction it will be much appreciated.  I don't use any @Audited annotations.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any classes from Hibernate 5.5 still hanging around in the classpath?  Either in your EAR or perhaps in Wildfly's shared classpath?

Comment: I have looked at my _mvn:dependency tree_ and also searched in my wildfly docker container and have not found any Hibernate 5.5 hanging around

Comment: Possibly Wildfly 29 is incompatible with Hibernate 6.  Possibly your particular copy of Hibernate 6 is buggy or inconsistent.  But I still suspect that you're overlooking some Hibernate 5 classes tucked in somewhere.  Maybe bundled into a JAR with something else.  I don't think this has anything to do with the contents of your persistence unit.

Comment: (Unless the jar with your entities also contains some Hibernate 5 classes.)

Comment: I have dropped back down to wildfly 27 using its hibernate 6.1.5.Final and it has deployed now . I guess I cant upgrade to wildfly 29 yet! Thanks for your help anyway